# Filtrations and topological ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, filtrations, topological-rings

At page $105$ of *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* of M. Atiyah, there is the following claim:

**C.** Given a ring $A$ and an ideal $I\subset A$, consider the filtration $(I^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, then we have a the $I$-adic topology on $A$. Then $A$ with this topology is a topological ring.

I'm able to check that $A$ is a topological group, but I have some problems to check that the multiplication map $A\times A\longrightarrow A$ is continuos.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck in the problem? It's just a matter of unwinding the definitions.

Comment: @anomaly 25 I think that to prove what I want it's enough to check that the preimage of $I^n$ is open for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now I know that this preimage is given by $\lbrace (x,y)\in A\times A  : xy\in I^n \rbrace$, but I don't know how to show that this last set is open in the topology of $A\times A$. Can you help me?

Comment: Write down a basis of the topology, and then write down the set you have in terms of it.

Comment: What I don't know do is just this.

Answer (score 1):

Over a commutative ring, any filter of ideals will define a ring topology. A filter of ideals is a set $\mathscr{F}$ of ideals such that

1. if $I\in\mathscr{F}$ and $J$ is any ideal with $I\subseteq J$, then $J\in\mathscr{F}$;
2. if $I,J\in\mathscr{F}$, then $I\cap J\in\mathscr{F}$.

If $\mathscr{S}$ is a set of ideals such that for $I,J\in\mathscr{S}$ there exists $K\in\mathscr{S}$ with $K\subseteq I\cap J$, then $\mathscr{F}$, consisting of the ideals containing some member of $\mathscr{S}$ is a filter of ideals and $\mathscr{S}$ is a basis for a filter.

A filtration, that is, a chain of ideals is certainly a basis for a filter. In particular the set of powers of a given ideal.

The topology associated to a filter $\mathscr{F}$ has as neighborhoods of $a\in A$ the sets of the form $a+I$, where $I\in\mathscr{F}$.

Continuity of addition is easy: let $a,b\in A$ and $I\in\mathscr{F}$. Then
$$
(a+I)+(b+I)=(a+b)+I
$$
Continuity of $a\mapsto-a$ is likewise obvious.

For multiplication, given $I\in\mathscr{F}$ we need to find $J,K\in\mathscr{F}$ such that
$$
(a+J)\cdot(b+K)\subseteq ab+I
$$
Notation: if $X,Y\subseteq A$, then $X\cdot Y=\{xy:x\in X, y\in Y\}$.

We can just choose $J=K=I$: indeed, if $x,y\in I$, we have
$$
(a+x)(b+y)=ab+(ay+xb+xy)
$$
and $ay+xb+xy\in I$.

Answer (score 0):

You can show this directly. Open subsets of $A$ are cosets of the form $I^n+a$, so take a pair $(b,c)$ that lies in the inverse image of $I^n+a$, i.e. $bc\in I^n+a$, and hence $I^n+bc=I^n+a$.

Now $(I^n+b)\times (I^n+c)$ is an open subset of $A\times A$, and $(I^n+b)(I^n+c)$ $=I^n+bc=I^n+a$, and hence $(I^n+b)\times (I^n+c)$ is contained in the inverse image of $I^n+a$, and it contains $(b,c)$. Therefore multiplication is continuous.